# Вывод данных двух Django-приложений одновременно

Tags: python, django

Создание собственного [шаблонного тега](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/howto/custom-template-tags.html) это единственный нормальный способ вывести данные 2х приложений на одной странице?

Comment: Не совсем очевидно, что подразумевается под `данными 2х приложений`.

Comment: Например одно приложение выводит список постов в блоге. А рядом другое приложение выводит количество сообщений на форуме. Ведь как я понял нельзя чтобы шаблоны запрашивали данные напрямую из модели. И должны делать это через `inclusion_tag`.

Comment: Я не вижу вообще необходимости использовать здесь теги. Забираете данные из модели во view, передаете в шаблон и отображаете. Отображаются данные, которые могут быть получены вообще из любого app.

Либо уточните.

Comment: @lilo.panic Если во view одного приложения я буду запрашивать данные другого приложения это будет излишним связыванием как мне кажется. И чтобы вывести 3е приложение как основное ему во view придется дописать тот-же запрос.

Comment: Ок, давайте разбираться. Для начала попрошу привести какие-то данные по архитектуре: моделям, view, ожидаемым результатам и т.д. Пока предполагаю, что у вас есть `/proj/app1` и `/proj/app2`. И задача в том, чтобы отрендерить шаблон в `app3`, отображающий данные первых двух. Если дело обстоит так, то обращаться к данным разных приложений совершенно нормально. Никакой inclusion_tag вам не нужен. Просто делайте внутри шаблона `{% include "app1/template.html" with qs=requested_qs var1=something %}`. Либо уточните желаемое.